# Why do people use scientific notation to write very large/very small numbers?

Tags: notation

I've seen numbers like these and 10 to the power of any some numbers is used sometimes for very large/very small numbers.  Any reason this is used?

Comment: Care to write out $10^{1000000}$ longhand?

Comment: There's no way for me.

Comment: Related: [E Scientific Exponential Notation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362070/e-scientific-exponential-notation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple example should be enough to illustrate why. Consider [Avogadro's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), $L$. Would you rather see
$$
L = 6.022141\times 10^{23}
$$
or
$$
L = 602214100000000000000000
$$
when reading an article, book, etc.?

Comment: @Chappers HA! Thanks for correcting my mindless blunder there.

Comment: I thought it best not to draw attention to that one :). I also made sure to check you had 24 digits there, although I did suppress my natural urge is to put thousands-separating commas in as well...