# E Scientific Exponential Notation

Tags: notation, exponentiation

Gday,

I have a question regarding scientific notation. Today I learnt that $a\operatorname{\mathbf{E}}b$ is the same as $a\cdot10^b$ and since myself and examiners (I'm in year 12) like neat working out I was trying to figure out if it is acceptable to use such notation and when searching the answer I came across the wikipedia page that said "The use of [**E**] notation is not encouraged in publications".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

So my question is why isn't or is **E** notation acceptable notation?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I would say if you are writing down (for homework or examination purposes) exponentials, never use calculator shorthand. Always use the Standard Index notation and the rules of indices to manipulate terms. To be controversial, in short, I would say the 'E' notation is *never* acceptable.

Comment: What you call "E notation" is convenient in computer output of very large or small floating point numbers, because the format can make efficient use of a programmatically specified width (adjusting the radix point to show most significant digits rather than leading or trailing zeros).  In publications the exponent-as-superscript can be typeset rather routinely, something that was impractical on early teletype and terminal computer output devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is acceptable however, to avoid confusion with other uses for the letter $E$ it is more common to write it in the form of $a \cdot 10^b$ as this allows no room for confusion.

Comment: I'm aware of Euler's number that could cause confusion but what other uses of E could cause confusion?

Comment: For example when working with sets we could have a set named $E$. This is quite common when talking about measurable sets.