Is there a difference between e- and scientific notation?
I noticed that some people use the terms "e-notation" and "scientific notation" interchangeably. Is there a real difference between them?

No. $\hspace{0pt}$

e takes one character to display, whereas
x10^ takes 4
The answer has more to do with practicality of calculator displays than with mathematics.


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362070/e-scientific-exponential-notation
